# Which color space the iOS devices is used?

Tags: ios, rgb, uicolor

When I use the MAC Digital Color Meter to detect the RGB color of the screen, the RGB values can be shown in sRGB, Adobe RGB, original RGBs spaces, etc. And they are slightly different.

I want to use these values in the iOS Xcode platform, and use `UIColor` class to represent them, which color space should I choose in the Digital Color Meter?

Thanks.

Comment: NOTE: OLD ANSWERS TO THIS QUESTION ARE OUT OF DATE BECAUSE APPLE CHANGED THE DEFAULT COLOR SPACE IN 2016 from sRGB to Display P3: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/821/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS itself [only supports device-dependent color spaces](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_color/dq_color.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH205-TPXREF128). I've heard that sRGB or Adobe RGB is closest to the iPhone/iPad display.

Answer (score 24):

iPhones definitely use sRGB. See this note on the page for `CGColorSpace Reference`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor?language=objc#1968626

Comment: +1 The relevant quote from that link: "iOS does not support ColorSync, so all assets should be provided in the **native device color space: sRGB.**"

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"Sorry, that page is currently unavailable."*

Comment: New link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor?language=objc#1968626. "These device color spaces correspond closely to the display characteristics of the sRGB color space."

Comment: No longer true. See https://medium.com/@volbap/working-efficiently-with-colors-in-xcode-bc4c58b16f9a "Whereas, newer Apple devices, such as the iPhone X, use a bigger color space that covers a wider gamut of colors, the Display-P3 standard (or, just P3 for short)"

Answer (score 2):

iPhone uses sRGB color space.

But for safety reasons, I suggest you use `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()` to generate the color space instead of `kCGColorSpaceSRGB`